# How to pass bash date into sql timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello i have code like this:

```
...AND o.creation_date > TO_DATE($DATE_TODAY, 'YYYYMMDD')...
```

When i want to pass variable into function TO_DATE it works.

But in another script, I have code like this...

```
    ...AND o.creation_date > TO_TIMESTAMP( $DATE_TODAY , 'YYYYMMDD')...
```

And in this case when i try pass $DATE_TODAY into function TO_TIMESTAMP i get error:

```
AND o.creation_date > TO_TIMESTAMP( 20220610 , 'YYYYMMDD') error in line 30:
ORA-00932 inconsistent datatypes Expected -, NUMBER obtained
```

I need to pass date in single quotes like '20220610', Is it possible to do this?

Comment: [bobby-tables.com: A guide to preventing SQL injection](https://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put single quotes in the script, there is no need to escape them. Just do:

```
AND o.creation_date > TO_TIMESTAMP( '$DATE_TODAY' , 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Comment: It actually works, I feel stupid that it could be solved so easily, I don't know why I thought it wouldn't work.